# jQuery syntax "&"

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have the following script:

```
  $("body").on("click",".admin-options form,.admin",function(event){

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Add A New Event Button Clicked!");
  //loads the action for the processing file
  var action=$(event.target).attr("name") || "edit_event",
  id=$(event.target).siblings("input[name=event_id]").val();

  id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id="+id:"";
 //loads the editing for and displays it

 $.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: processFile,
 data: "action="+action+id,
 success: function(data){
    //Hides the form
    var form=$(data).hide(),
    //Make sure the modal window exists
    modal=fx.initModal()
              .children(":not(.modalclosebtn)")
              .remove()
              .end();
    //call the boxin function to create the modal overlay
    fx.boxin(null,modal);
    //load the form into the window ->fades in content->adds a class to the     form
    form.appendTo(modal)
        .addClass("edit-form")
        .fadeIn("slow");
          },
    error: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    }

});
});
```

My question is very simple. It might sound funny, but nowhere is an answer for it.I'm trying to understand the code 100%, so the only think is not really clear for me:
this line 
id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id="+id:"";
what "&" exactly, and what is the purpose of the syntax form "+id:"

Comment: That's part of URL query string syntax. `&` separates each of the URL parameters.

Comment: Aren't you familiar with URLs like `www.something.com?param1=value&param2=value`?

Comment: Not really, but now I know what to google. Thanks.

Comment: This data: "action="+action+id, would becomes something like this "action="+"edit_event"+"&event_id="1542 ==> action=edit_event&event_id=1542

Comment: Thank you for you answers. So what i've got as a big picture: in order to exchange data between php and jquery we have to extract it from the url. Then we cast the extracted string to a number and use it to make the action parameter in the ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line first checks if id is not null AND  is equal to another variable. +id is for casting **id** variable to a number. The first check prevents the code from breaking if **id** is null.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer. Both Justus' answers say the same thing, and they're both incorrect for the code given in the OP

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is the line in question **id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id="+id:"";**

Comment: Exactly. As I keep telling you, that's concatenating a string

Answer (score 1):

The data you are passing in the ajax attribute is the query string form that is something like this

```
www.example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

And if you are asking for this line

```
id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id="+id:"";
```

This is called ternary operator. The expression before question mark will return either true or false. If it returns true your expression would be the value before the : operator and if it returns false it would return the value after : operator.

```
result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax +id in jquery is used to cast to variable to a number.

Comment: Thats true, but not for this case. Here it's being used to concatenate a string.

Comment: I disagree, if it's concatenation it would be outside the double quotes

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan. In this case he is calling to some ajax resourse, make strings based on conditions (data: "action="+action+id)

Comment: @JustusIkara have you read the code? It's clearly concatenating a string

Comment: **id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id="+id:""** is different from  **id=(id!=undefined)?"&event_id=+"id:"";**